# Scala lower type bound 'is a subtype' restriction on method arguments

Tags: scala

In Scala, why does setting lower type bounds on a method type parameter not enforce the "is a super-type" restriction on the method arguements ?

```
object TypeBounds extends App {
  class MotorVehicle
  class Truck extends MotorVehicle
  class Car extends MotorVehicle
  class Saloon extends Car
  class HatchBackSaloon extends Saloon

  def lowerTypeBound[C >: Car](c: C): C = c

  def upperTypeBound[C <: Car](c: C): C = c

  // Works. HatchBackSaloon is a sub class of Car
  println(upperTypeBound(new HatchBackSaloon())) 

  // as expected doesn't compile. Truck is not a subclass of Car    
  println(upperTypeBound( new Truck()))  

  // Compiles and runs, but why ?  HatchBackSaloon is not a super class of Car.
  println(lowerTypeBound(new HatchBackSaloon())) 

}
```

Comment: I suppose this kind of answers my question [How does the Java compiler perform type erasure for lower bounded wildcards?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25480172/how-does-the-java-compiler-perform-type-erasure-for-lower-bounded-wildcards)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`C` in your example is materialized as `Car`, not `HatchbackSaloon`.

A function looking like `def lowerTypeBound(c: Car): Car` can accept arguments of type `HatchbackSaloon`, it is not surprising, right?

Try something like this:

```
val result: HatchBackSaloon = lowerTypeBound(new HatchBackSaloon)
```

This will not compile, because it would require `C` to be `HatchbackSaloon`, which is not a superclass of `Car`. But this will work:

```
val result: MotorVehicle = lowerTypeBound(new HatchbackSaloon)
```

because `C` is `MotorVehicle` here, and that is allowed.